# Godot - How to use the VideoPlayer node to play .ogv files

Tags: godot

I'm using the Godot game engine to create a mobile app. The app requires a scene to play some videos (Godot only plays `.ogv` files). Testing the video scene on a Mac laptop is successful when I run it by clicking on the 'play the project' button. But testing failed when I install it onto the device i.e. the video is not visible / does not play on a mobile device. However, all my other non-video scenes work on the mobile device.

**Additional info**: 
1. The video size is 5.3MB and is ogv.
2. The video is set to autoplay. 
3. The 'VideoPlayer' node dimensions are correct with respect to the scene dimensions. 
4. The 'VideoPLayer' node has the correct reference to the stream file and is set to visible (with the correct white 'Modulate' colour).

**How I tried to fix this**:
1. Downloaded a working .ogv demo online since this has not ben converted.
2. Converted my m4v to ogv using several different software.
3. Deleted the 'VideoPlayer' node and coded the video player into the scene script.

...my attempts at fixing did not work

Please, can you help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add `*.ogv` to the non-resource export filter in your export preset. You need to do this since Godot does not consider videos as imported resources, so they won't be exported with other project files by default.

[Adding *.ogv to an export preset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLJaI.png)